# Using top N in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

statement 1

```
UPDATE TOP(1) employee 
    SET GivenName = 'Alex', 
        LastName = 'Smith' 
WHERE ID = 1
```

statement 2

```
UPDATE employee 
    SET GivenName = 'ALEX', 
        LastName = 'Smith' 
WHERE ID IN (
                SELECT TOP (1) 
                FROM employee 
                WHERE ID = 1 
                ORDER BY ID ASC
```

I have tried the above but both are not working.

Does anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update one row, then you can use `limit`:

```
UPDATE employee
    SET GivenName = 'Alex',
        LastName = 'Smith'
    WHERE ID = 1
    LIMIT 1;
```

That said, I would expect `id` to be unique, so no `LIMIT` is necessary.